# Drools Fusion Temporal Operator Duration Error/Declaring Events

Tags: java, drools, temporal, drools-fusion

I have been trying to process a duration property in my java bean, but it does not seem to be processing. I have tried to declare it two ways: The first is by grabbing the existing class and declaring it as an event inside the DRL. Here is my code.

```
package com.sample;

import com.sample.Instance;

declare Instance
@role(event)
@duration(durationTime)
end

rule "Lisa Evans"
when
    $instance : Instance (code == "Lisa Evans - Accel : 0.00 - 2.00") from    entry-point "Stream"
then
    entryPoints["Correlate"].insert($instance);
end

rule "Kirsty Smith" 
when
    $instance : Instance (code == "Kirsty Smith - Accel : 0.00 - 2.00") from entry-point "Stream"
then
    entryPoints["Correlate"].insert($instance);
end

rule "Correlate"
when
    $i1 : Instance () from entry-point "Correlate"
    $i2: Instance (this after $i1)

then
    System.out.println("Duration: " + $i1.getDuration());
end
```

But I keep getting the error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while creating KieBase[Message [id=1, level=ERROR, path=Ruleset.drl, line=5, column=0
   text=Error processing @duration for TypeDeclaration 'com.sample.Instance': cannot access the field 'durationTime']]"

The second way i'm declaring it is in my Java Class:

```
package com.sample;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.kie.api.definition.type.Role;
import org.kie.api.definition.type.Duration;

@Role(Role.Type.EVENT)
@Duration("durationTime")

@XmlRootElement (name = "instance")
public class Instance implements Comparable<Instance>
{

int id;
double startValue;
double endValue;
long durationTime;
String Code;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
@XmlElement (name = "ID")
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public double getStart() {
    return startValue;
}
@XmlElement
public void setStart(double start) {
    this.startValue = start;
}
public double getEnd() {
    return endValue;
}
@XmlElement
public void setEnd(double end) {
    this.endValue = end;
}

public long getDuration() {
    return durationTime = (long) ((this.endValue - this.startValue) * 1000);
}

public String getCode() {
    return Code;
}
@XmlElement
public void setCode(String code) {
    Code = code;
}
@Override
public int compareTo(Instance o) {
    return Double.compare(this.getEnd(), o.getEnd());

}

}
```

And it still doesnt work as im getting the same error. In the DRL, I do not get the error if i declare the object as an event without the duration property, as well as declaring it also as an event role inside the object, even with the duration property. Running it with the temporal rule at the bottom, it does not fire however. And it seems like a basic rule that should fire.

If I remove the declared event type in the DRL i get the error, however. Without touching the java bean.

Summary: Declared the Event Type inside the java bean inc. duration property: doesnt like the duration property/cant access it. Declared it in the DRL for the existing class inc. duration property. Doesnt like it either. Runs no error when I have the java bean event declaration untouched (inc duration) but declared the event type in the DRL with no duration property. Basic temporal operator does not work however when their is no error.

Very confused. Could be doing multiple things wrong. Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: The code for class Instance is messed up but it seems that the getter doesn't match the field durationTime - stick to JavaBean conventions!

Comment: What do you mean it is messed up?

Comment: Mussed up, muddled up, not in order, confused. Two package statements, two class headers, more duplications.

Comment: Ahhh sorry! I just noticed and corrected.

For the @duration problem, I managed to clear the error by replacing "getDuration" with the same name of the variable - durationTime.

Why has it done this though? I documentation says that it has to be field? not a method..

Could be a background java answer I am aware.

Also, any tips to know if it has properly worked? I tried calling that simple temporal rule in the drl there with System.out.println("MATCH") instead of the System.out.println("Duration: " + $i1.getDuration()); But no luck.

Thank you.

Comment: The JavaBeans convention is: If the field is called xyzAbc, the getter must be called getXyzAbc. Google the specs.